# SQL Server pivot specified columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm struggling with a query output issue.  Please see sample data :

```
CREATE TABLE #Subject (ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, Name NVARCHAR(50))
CREATE TABLE #Student (ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, Name NVARCHAR(50))
CREATE TABLE #Grade (ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
       StudentID INT REFERENCES #Student(ID),
       SubjectID INT REFERENCES #Subject(ID),
       Grade NVARCHAR(50), GradeText NVARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO #Subject ( Name ) VALUES
(N'Maths'),
(N'Physics'),
(N'English')

INSERT INTO #Student ( Name ) VALUES
(N'Joe'),
(N'Tom'),
(N'Sally'),
(N'Fred'),
(N'Kim')

INSERT INTO #Grade
    (  StudentID, SubjectID, Grade, GradeText ) VALUES
(1,1,'Current','A'),
(2,3,'Expected','C'),
(3,2,'Mid','F'),
(4,1,'Final','B'),
(5,2,'Pre','C'),
(2,3,'Start','A'),
(3,1,'Current','A'),
( 1,2,'Expected','B'),
( 4,1,'Final','D'),
( 5,3,'Mid','E')

SELECT * FROM #Student
SELECT * FROM #Subject
SELECT * FROM #Grade
```

For the grade output I want to set some of the important grade types in the grade column to be their OWN columns. i.e. Current, Final I would like to be created as their own columns with associated grades, but the others can just be listed as they're not as important.  This is a very simple example, the data I'm working with is much more complicated.

Is their a way to specify important columns to be created as their own columns and other data to just be listed as per normal? Also, all the pivot examples I've seen are querying from one table.  What happens when you're query has many joins?

Comment: Thanks for the sample data (I've cleaned it up some to better fit on screen). What are your expected results from this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you aiming at something like this:

```
;with x as (
    select *
    from (
        select StudentID, SubjectID, Grade, GradeText, Grade as grade_1, GradeText as GradeText_1
            from (
            select *
            from #Grade 
        ) as x
    ) as source
    pivot (
        max(GradeText_1)
        for Grade_1 in ([Current], [Final])
    ) as pvt
)
select sub.Name as Subject, st.Name as Student, Grade, GradeText, [Current], Final
from x
inner join #Subject sub on x.SubjectID = sub.ID
inner join #Student st on x.StudentID = st.ID
```

Comment: Yes i believe that's exactly what i'm after! Can you explain what the MAX function is doing in this situation?  MAX just selects highest number doesn't it? How does it apply in this scenario?

Comment: Just consider it a NOOP in this context, it's just a single value per row. (but an agregate function is requird nevertheless)

Comment: A "command that effectively does nothing at all",  according to Wikipedia. Short for No Operation

Comment: an issue i'm having, the pivot query seems to be excluding some of my results.  Two of my columns current and expected do not seem to be showing, however i can clearly see when i query the root table and only filter either current or expected.  Is this something to do with the MAX and null values or something?

Comment: Post your code and sample data, I can't tell otherwise.

Comment: hi apologies one of my subsequent joins was filtering some of the pivot data.  Thanks for your help.